# During back-propagation getting ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,3) (1,4)

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network, backpropagation

I had created a neural network with one hidden layer with 3 nodes, the sigmoid function was used as the activation function

**The input layer** (2 nodes):
 
X | X is a matrix with size (1x2)

**Hidden Layer** (3 nodes): 
W1 => will have a size (3x2) 
Z1 = X.(W1.T) + b 
A1 = σ(Z) | (W1.T) is the transpose of matrix W 
 

**Output Layer** (4 nodes): 
W2 => will have a size (4x3) 
Z2 = A1.(W2.T) + b 
A2 = σ(Z) 
E = 0.5*(Y- A2)^2 | Y is a matrix with size (1x4)

I wanted to calculate how W of hidden layer affects the E (cost function), applying the chain rule

dEdW1 = dEdA2 * dA2dZ2 * dZ2dA1 * dA1dZ1 * dZ1dW1 
      = (A2-Y) * (σ(Z2)*(1-σ(Z2))) * W2.T * (σ(Z1)*(1-σ(Z1))) * X
matrix sizes=> (1x4) * (1x4) * (3x4) * (1x3) * (1x2)

I know there is something wrong with my derivatives as I cannot multiply the matrices (they come in different sizes), can someone point out how to fix this
Here is the implementation:

```
class Sigmoid:

def sigmoid(self, Z):
    return (1 / (1 + numpy.exp(-Z)))

# change in sigmoid w.r.t Z
def dsigmoiddZ(self, Z):
    return self.sigmoid(Z) * (1 - self.sigmoid(Z))

class PrimaryLayer:

def __init__(self, node_count):
    self.node_count = node_count
    self.previous_layer = None
    self.next_layer = None
    self.Z = None
    self.A = None

class SecondaryLayer(PrimaryLayer):

def __init__(self, node_count, previous_layer):
    super().__init__(node_count)
    self.dEdW = None
    self.set_previous_layer(previous_layer)
    self.set_next_layer_to_self()
    self.set_W()
    self.set_b()
    self.set_Z()
    self.set_A()

def set_previous_layer(self, previous_layer):
    self.previous_layer = previous_layer

# This points the next_layer of previous_layer to self
def set_next_layer_to_self(self):
    self.previous_layer.next_layer = self

# Randomly generate weights for this layer
def set_W(self):
    self.W = numpy.random.random((self.node_count, self.previous_layer.node_count))

def set_b(self):
    self.b = numpy.random.random()

def set_W_adjusted(self, learning_rate):
    self.W_adjusted = W_adjusted

def set_Z(self):

    previous_layer = self.previous_layer

    if previous_layer.previous_layer is not None:
        self.Z = numpy.dot(previous_layer.A, self.W.T) + self.b
    else:
        #if previous_layer.previos_layer = None then it is the Input Layer
        self.Z = numpy.dot(previous_layer.X, self.W.T) + self.b

def set_A(self):
    self.A = Sigmoid().sigmoid(self.Z)

def set_dAdZ(self):
    self.dAdZ = self.A * (1 - self.A)

def set_dZdW(self):
    self.dZdW = self.A

class InputLayer(PrimaryLayer):

def __init__(self, node_count, X):
    super().__init__(node_count)
    self.X = X

class OutputLayer(SecondaryLayer):

def __init__(self, node_count, previous_layer, Y):   
    super().__init__(node_count, previous_layer)
    self.Y = Y
    self.set_E()

def set_E(self):
    self.E = ((1 / 2) * numpy.square(self.Y - self.A))

def set_dEdA(self):
    self.dEdA = self.A - self.Y

def set_dEdW(self):
    self.set_dEdA()
    self.set_dAdZ()
    self.set_dZdW()
    self.dEdW = self.dEdA * self.dAdZ * self.dZdW

class HiddenLayer(SecondaryLayer):

def __init__(self, node_count, previous_layer):
    super().__init__(node_count, previous_layer)

def set_dEdW(self):
    self.set_dAdZ()
    self.set_dZdW()
    self.dEdW = self.dAdZ * self.dZdW * self.calculate_derivative(self.next_layer)

#calculate derivatives for other layer    
def calculate_derivative(self, next_layer):

    this_layer = next_layer

    if this_layer.next_layer is None:

    # the outputlayer
        this_layer.set_dAdZ()
        this_layer.set_dEdA()
        dAdZ = this_layer.dAdZ
        dEdA = this_layer.dEdA
        return dAdZ * dEdA

    elif this_layer is not None:

        this_layer.set_dAdZ()
        # How a layer's Z changes w.r.t previous layer's A    
        dZdA = this_layer.W.T
        # How currrent layer's A changes w.r.t current layer's Z    
        dAdZ = this_layer.dAdZ
        return dZdA * dAdZ * self.calculate_derivative(this_layer.next_layer)

class NeuralNetwork:

def __init__(self):

    X = numpy.array([[1, 1]])
    Y = numpy.array([[2, 2, 2, 2]])

    # create layers and foward propagate
    self.input_layer = InputLayer(2, X)
    self.h1 = HiddenLayer(3, self.input_layer)
    self.output_layer = OutputLayer(4, self.h1, Y)

    self.forward_propagation(self.input_layer)
    self.back_propagation(self.output_layer)

def forward_propagation(self, input_layer):
    current_layer = input_layer.next_layer     
    if current_layer is not None:
        current_layer.set_Z()
        current_layer.set_A()

        # if current layer is a outputlayer
        if current_layer.next_layer is None:
            current_layer.set_E()

        self.forward_propagation(current_layer)

def back_propagation(self, output_layer):
    current_layer = output_layer

    # loop through all NON Input layers
    if current_layer.previous_layer is not None:
        current_layer.set_dEdW()

    print(current_layer.dEdW)
    self.back_propagation(current_layer.previous_layer)

nn = NeuralNetwork()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably transpose your matrices.

Matrices multiplication work like "AxB  * BxC  =  AxC", so you will not be able to multiply (1x4) * (3x4). Try transposing the second one, so you'll have a (1x4)*(4x3) multiplication.

And also reorder the rest, so it should look like (4x1)*(1x4)*(4x3)*(3x1)*(1x2)

Comment: That would break the meaning of dEdW.

Comment: Either way, you have to transform your matrices in some way to fit a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your weight matrices. Suppose the following: Given an input matrix X of dimensions 4x2 (that is you have 4 inputs - aka your rows - and each input has a dimensionality of 2 elements) for example:

> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]

If your hidden layer has 4 neurons, your w0 weight matrix turns out to be of size 2x4. You'll have a b0 bias vector of 4 elements and upon calculating the activation on this layer, you'll end up with:

```
z1 = X @ w0 + b0  # 4x2 * 2x4 + 1x4 = 4x4
a1 = f(z1)  # 4x4
```

Then let's say in the output layer you have 2 elements which makes your w1 matrix of size 4x2 and your b1 vector of size 2. Doing the maths gives:

```
z2 = a1 @ w1 + b1  # 4x4 * 4x2 + 1x2 = 4x2
a2  = f(z)  # 4x2
```

During backpropagation you calculate a delta for each layer as:

```
d_O = (Y - T) * f'(z2)
d_H = d_O @ W1.T * f'(z1)
```

where Y is your network's guess of size: 4x2

T are the training labels, so they must match up: 4x2

The multiplication is an element-wise multiplication, which makes your

> d_O of size 4x2

Calculating the hidden layer delta dimension is pretty similar:

d_O: 4x2

W1 is of size 4x2, so the transpose is 2x4, with @ being the standard matrix multiplication your d_H dimension turns out as:

> d_H of size 4x4

For updating your weights then you have:

```
dW1 := a1.T @ d_O
dW2 := X.T @ d_H
```

where a1 is a 4x4 matrix, d_O is a 4x2 matrix, which makes your dW1 a 4x2 matrix. W1 was of size 4x2.

X is your input matrix of size 4x2, X.T is then 2x4, and d_H was 4x4, which makes dW0 a 2x4. Your original W0 was 2x4.

Bias deltas are lot simpler:

```
db1 = np.sum(d_O, axis=0)
db0 = np.sum(d_H, axis=0)
```